# CodeIgniter: some doubts about HMVC and Views

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I've just discovered HMVC Modular Extension for CodeIgniter https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home and it seems perfect for my needs but I have some question.

Let's say I have two controllers:

- **Site** which is the main controller and is used to show site's pages and may call methods of Users controller for example to show a form
- **User** controller is used to authenticate users, to show login/sign up forms...

Now I have these questions:

1. If the user access the **User controller** directly (mysite.com/user/method) I want to show a full page while if i load a method of **User** from within the **Site controller** I want to show only a form (for example), is this possible?
2. What happens to view of a module loaded from another module: is the view shown automatically or i need to show it manually and how does the view behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you method is being called via Modules::run()

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser.

Eg:

```
//put underscore in front to prevent uri access to this method.
public function _module1()
{
     $this->load->view('partial_view', array('some data'=>'some data'), TRUE)
}
```

call it inside your **SITE view** easily

```
Modules::run('User/_module1')
// should show whatever is in partial_view ie: a form

//an alternative is to pass in any params if the method requires them
Modules::run('User/_module1', $param)
```

Comment: no modules::run is calling your class/method not the other way round.  By adding the third param into the view loader, it will retrieve the view as a string.  SO no output is rendered to the browser, it can now be used like an include